# Change Bullets as power

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a 2d game and I want my player to be able to change bullets when he collides with an object(power) and destroy that object. I have a script and I was thinking that I need to implement 2 variables prefab ON/Off but now thinking much more I want to change with the help of a tag ( My player has in his script a public Rigidbody2D bullet) and this function

```css
void Fire()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            var firedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
            firedBullet.AddForce(barrel.up * bulletSpeed);
        }
    }
```

this is the script that I was working on for switching bullets but I think it will not work to change a bullet that I add in the inspector for the Character script , to disable from this script and add other bullet . How I can make it by tag?

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject pickupEffect;
    public GameObject[] DisablePrefab;
    public GameObject[] EnablePrefab;
    public int selectBullet = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Bullet(Character bullet)
    {
        var effect = Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        foreach (GameObject disable in DisablePrefab)
        {
            disable.SetActive(false);
        }
        foreach (GameObject enable in EnablePrefab)
        {
            enable.SetActive(true);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(effect, 3.0f);
    }
  
}
```

and I try this think with a BulletSwitch script to call the function from Weapon Switching script

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Character bullet;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!bullet) bullet = GetComponent<Character>();

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // or whatever tag your powerups have
        if (!other.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Registered a collision but with wrong tag: {other.tag}", this);
            return;
        }

        var Bullet = other.GetComponent<WeaponSwitching>();
        if (!Bullet)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Object {other.name} is tagged PowerUp but has no PowerUp component attached", this);
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Found powerup, pick it up!", this);
        Bullet.Bullet(bullet);
    }
}
```

[inspector character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLTEi.png)

after my player collides with an object the bullets disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of prefabs and change to the correct bullet type when you hit a powerup by setting a CurrentBulletType variable to one of the types from the array. So when you hit powerup X, change bullet type to one of the types from the array.

```
public GameObject currentPrefab;
public GameObject[] bulletPrefabs;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    string tagString = other.tag;
    bool foundObject = true;
    switch (tagString)
    {
        case "standard bullet":
            currentPrefab = bulletPrefabs[0];
            break;
        case "fancy bullet":
            currentPrefab = bulletPrefabs[1];
            break;
        case "even fancier bullet":
            currentPrefab = bulletPrefabs[2];
            break;
        default:
            foundObject = false;
            break;
    }
    if (foundObject) other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

You can instead use a dictionary to directly reference the correct prefab by string name (tag) to make it easy to add more bullet types.

```
//dictionairy to reference bullet types quickly
public Dictionary<string, BulletTypes> bulletLibrary = new Dictionary<string, BulletTypes>();
//set these in the inspector
public BulletTypes[] bulletTypes;

[System.Serializable]
public struct BulletTypes
{
    public string bulletName;
    public GameObject prefab;
    //public int bulletPower; //more data if you wish
}

private void Start()
{
    //fill the dictionary based on the filled bullet type array in inspector
    for (int i = 0; i < bulletTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bulletTypes[i].bulletName != "")
            bulletLibrary.Add(bulletTypes[i].bulletName, bulletTypes[i]);
        else
            print("bullet added, but name empty");
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    string tagString = other.tag;

    //if the collided tag is in the dictionary, we can reference the bullet type from that dictionairy
    if (bulletLibrary.ContainsKey(tagString))
    {
        print("spawn: " + bulletLibrary[tagString].bulletName);
        print("prefab: " + bulletLibrary[tagString].prefab);

        //all the data you need is in: bulletLibrary[tagString];
        //Bullet.Bullet(bulletLibrary[tagString]);
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Sidenote: If you spawn a lot of bullets, you can use pooling. [SimplePool](https://gist.github.com/quill18/5a7cfffae68892621267) is nice and easy for this. Instead of calling: instantiate and destroy, you call: SimplePool.Spawn() and SimplePool.DeSpawn().

If you have any more questions on this feel free to ask ;)

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. and UnityException: FindObjectsOfType can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function. [ this are the error I get , I should add the first script to my player.cs ? ]

Comment: Where do you get this error? Can you post that part of your script?

Comment: currentPrefab = bulletPrefabs[1];

Comment: I resolve the error but still doesn't change my bullets

Comment: The first script in my answer (the one you're using) should turn the currentBullet gameobject into the bullet from the array when you hit a tag. If this is the case, the foundObject bool becomes true. Check if this is indeed the case by calling Debug.Log("Object should change: "+foundObject);